# How to Delete a row on Page29 in a datatable (jquery/javascript) and stay on the same Page29 after ajax call

Tags: jquery, datatables

CODE:

```
 var tableDel = $('#tbl_main').DataTable();
   var values=numbers;

 $('#tbl_main tbody').on('click', 'button.DeleteRecordFromRow', function           () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRowDetails", "Lead")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(values),
            success: function (data)
            {
        tableDel.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
                alert("success");
                //$("#tbl_main").dataTable().fnDraw();
                //tableDel.ajax.reload();
            },

  error: function (data)
            {        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking for here, sorry. Do you want to click a button, with a class of DeleteRecordFromRow, which removes the whole row from the table without altering the pagination etc? If so how does the backend know which row to remove?

Comment: We are sending ID to the controller method to delete the row in the db

Comment: If that's the case then you perhaps need to listen to your server and check that the relevant record has been deleted before deleting the row. If the `success` returns the `id` then you'll know which row to remove and then call `.draw(false)` on the table.